# Mac M1 Pip How to Solve Error Building Wheel for h5py?

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1, h5py

I am getting this error when trying to install h5py on my Mac:

**error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1**

**ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py**

Python and hdf5 were installed with homebrew.

Some more Info:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.7

$pip -V
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the architecture arm64 instead of x86_64, use x86_64 by typing this in terminal:

```
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh
```

Comment: Apple M1 is an ARM based system. Why would the topicstarter use x86 architecture on ARM?